# Arithmetic expression in redirection

Tags: linux, bash

What is the difference between these two:

```
cnt=1
head -n $((++cnt)) /etc/passwd >/dev/null
echo $cnt # prints 2
```

and

```
cnt=1
date >$((++cnt)).txt # creates file "2.txt"
echo $cnt # prints 1
```

My question is why in the second example 1 is printed.
Note:

```
cnt=1
(cnt=5)
echo $cnt # prints 1
```

I know why this will print 1. Is the redirection executed in a subshell too? If yes, where is that described?

Comment: Here's [shellcheck's description](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2257) of the problem.

Comment: @oguzismail, is it described somewhere that the redirections are performed in a subshell?

Comment: @Lassie Seems that it is in fact - try `strace -f bash -c 'cnt=1; date > $((++cnt)).txt' |& egrep 'txt|clone'`. But then I guess you knew that. Whether it is documented I couldn't say.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a concrete citation for *why* this behavior exists, but going off the notes in [SC2257](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2257)* there are some interesting points to note in the manual.

> When a simple command **other than a builtin or shell function** is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution environment 
> [§3.7.3 Command Execution Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html)

This reflects what SC2257 notes, though it's unclear about which environment the redirection's value is evaluated in.  However [§3.1.1 Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html#Shell-Operation) seems to say that redirection happens *before* this execution (sub)environment is invoked:

> Basically, the shell does the following: 
> ...
>
> 4. Performs the various shell expansions....
> 5. Performs any necessary redirections and removes the redirection operators and their operands from the argument list.
> 6. Executes the command.

We can see that this isn't limited to [arithmetic expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html) but also other state-changing expansions like `:=`:

```
$ bash -c 'date >"${word:=wow}.txt"; echo "word=${word}"'
word=

$ bash -c 'echo >"${word:=wow}.txt"; echo "word=${word}"'
word=wow
```

Interestingly, this does not appear to be a (well-defined) subshell environment, because [`BASH_SUBSHELL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) remains set to `0`:

```
$ date >"${word:=$BASH_SUBSHELL}.txt"; ls
0.txt
```

We can also check some other shells, and see that `zsh` has the same behavior, though `dash` does not:

```
$ zsh -c 'date >"${word:=wow}.txt"; echo "word=${word}"'
word=

$ zsh -c 'echo >"${word:=wow}.txt"; echo "word=${word}"'
word=wow

$ dash -c 'date >"${word:=wow}.txt"; echo "word=${word}"'
word=wow

$ dash -c 'echo >"${word:=wow}.txt"; echo "word=${word}"'
word=wow
```

I skimmed the [`zsh` guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/) but didn't find an exact mention of this behavior there either.

**Needless to say**, this does not appear to be well-documented behavior, so it's fortunate that ShellCheck can help catch it. It does however appear to be long-standing behavior, it's reproducible in Bash 3, 4, and 5.

<sub>* Unfortunately the [commit that added SC2257](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/commit/7b998239afe21e89c1c57e7f26947fb4b640214f) doesn't link to an Issue or any other further context.</sub>

Comment: Very long-standing behavior, at least since '96 ([726f6388](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/?id=726f63884db0132f01745f1fb4465e6621088ccf)).

Answer (score 1):

Shellcheck's advice is sound; sometimes redirections are performed in subshells. However, the crux of this behavior is *when* expansions occur:

```
bind_int_variable          variables.c:3410    cnt = 2, late binding
expr_bind_variable         expr.c:336          
exp0                       expr.c:1040         
exp1                       expr.c:1007         
exppower                   expr.c:962          
expmuldiv                  expr.c:887          
exp3                       expr.c:861          
expshift                   expr.c:837          
exp4                       expr.c:807          
exp5                       expr.c:785          
expband                    expr.c:767          
expbxor                    expr.c:748          
expbor                     expr.c:729          
expland                    expr.c:702          
explor                     expr.c:674          
expcond                    expr.c:627          
expassign                  expr.c:512          
expcomma                   expr.c:492          
subexpr                    expr.c:474          
evalexp                    expr.c:439          
param_expand               subst.c:9498        parameter expansion, including arith subst
expand_word_internal       subst.c:9990        
shell_expand_word_list     subst.c:11335       
expand_word_list_internal  subst.c:11459       
expand_words_no_vars       subst.c:10988       
redirection_expand         redir.c:287         expansions post-fork()
do_redirection_internal    redir.c:844         
do_redirections            redir.c:230         redirections are done in child process
execute_disk_command       execute_cmd.c:5418  fork to run date(1)
execute_simple_command     execute_cmd.c:4547  
execute_command_internal   execute_cmd.c:842   
execute_command            execute_cmd.c:394   
reader_loop                eval.c:175          
main                       shell.c:805
```

When execute_disk_command() is called, it forks and then executes date(1). After the fork() and before the execve(), redirections and additional expansions are done (via do_redirections()). Variables expanded and bound post-fork will not reflect in the parent shell.

From BASH's perspective, however, this is just a simple command rather than a subshell command. This is an implicit subshell.

---

See [execute_disk_command() in execute_cmd.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?id=9e49d343e3cd7e20dad1b86ebfb764e8027596a7#n5294)

```
Execute a simple command that is hopefully defined in a disk file
somewhere.
1) fork ()
2) connect pipes
3) look up the command
4) do redirections
5) execve ()
6) If the execve failed, see if the file has executable mode set.
If so, and it isn't a directory, then execute its contents as
a shell script.
```

(references taken from commit 9e49d343e3cd7e20dad1b86ebfb764e8027596a7 [[browse tree](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/?id=9e49d343e3cd7e20dad1b86ebfb764e8027596a7)])

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    let cnt=1
    echo `date` > "$((++cnt))".txt
    echo $cnt
```

(editing my answer)
@alaniwi pointed out that strace clearly shows a clone. And I agree with P.P that it does not indicate a subshell being there and having scoured the documentation I did not find a direct reference for it.

**EDIT**:command substitution, process substitutions forks a subshell. I do want to quote the following from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment

```
Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment ...
```

This may hold some more answers :

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html (search for command substitution)
- https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html
- https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: Of course, there's a `clone` call because `date` has to be executed. But that doesn't say anything about whether the redirection happens in a subshell.

Comment: @P.P not all redirections are performed in subshells, only disk commands and explicit subshell commands.

Comment: @BhaskarTallamraju "arithmetic expansions forks a subshell." this is not true

Comment: @Rafael How is what you're saying related to my comment?